# Call REST API From .net application

Tags: rest-api, integration, .net

I have below code to fetch account details from salesforce using REST API. But i am getting bad request status in the response(400). Could you please help me on this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;

public class DemoController
    {

    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string endPOINTURL = String.Format("https://chaithraservicecloudsso-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sObjects/Account");

                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPOINTURL);

                httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
                httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/Json";
                //httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer 00D280000017weU!ARgA_DoNotPublishYourFullSessionId__L7CvP7t9DxTn3dF3MBxy");

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                Console.WriteLine("Response" + httpResponse);
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is case sensitive.

Note the capital you have in your URL:

> /services/data/v37.0/s**O**bjects/Account

Instead you want:

> /services/data/v39.0/s**o**bjects/Account

If in doubt, [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) is a great tool to test the REST API calls out from.

---

Also, you need to specify the subdomain on the endpoint.

You endpoint should change from:

> https:// **test.** salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sObjects/Account

To something like:

> https:// **cs14.** salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Account

The specific subdomain you require will depend on which pod/instance you org is hosted on. Typically when you establish the SessionID you will also get the ServerURL back that needs to be used for subsequent requests.

---

I used you code verbatim from the question from a C# console application. It worked fine after I corrected the endpoint URL as per the case sensitivity not above.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string endPOINTURL = String.Format("https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Account");

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPOINTURL);

        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/Json";
        //httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer 00D280000017weU!ARgA_DoNotPublishYourFullSessionId_jzISX7MBtOriTqkF8Hp3LzZh2OOh_L7CvP7t9DxTn3dF3MBxy");

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine("Response" + httpResponse);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

[image]

---

As per the comments, the last part of the puzzle would be ensuring you have TLS 1.2 support from both the .NET framework and the operating system. See [Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1)

Comment: Nope..I tried..it did not work..

Comment: @ChaithraKN You also need to change the `test.` subdomain to the correct value for you pod/instance. If it is a sandbox it will be something like: `https://cs15.salesforce.com/`

Comment: Yes.. I have tried that too.. It is not working

Comment: @ChaithraKN Can you update your question to append your current call? There might be something more subtle happening. Also, did you get it to work in Workbench? When you do, you can pull the raw HTTP GET request from the browser developer tools.

Comment: Updated current endpoint URL in the code and as well session id. It works in workbench and also Postman.

Comment: @ChaithraKN Seems to work fine for me. Note that the casing for `sObjects` was still off in the question. Only other thing you might need to check is TLS 1.2 support. Both at the .NET Framework level and at the OS level.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to check TLS 1.2 support for .NET Framework and at the OS level. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ChaithraKN TLS support is a [whole other question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/165988/102). Best to pursue that separately.

Comment: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
This line worked for me. Thank u :)

Comment: @ChaithraKN Great. If your problem is solved please consider using the tick mark to indicate as such.